# Is the Commerce Connect Starter Kit example compatible with Sitecore 9?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have developers at my company trying to update the Sitecore Commerce Connect Starter Kit (https://github.com/Sitecore/Commerce-Connect-StarterKit) to Sitecore 9 so they can test a module we developed internally. They ran the upgrade wizard, but afterward, the site wouldn't run and would throw an error on load:

**"Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository, Sitecore.Analytics"**

I'm currently trying to resolve their issues, but does anyone have experience upgrading the Starter Kit to SC9? Is it even compatible?